# VMWare Horizon Client is very slow

Tags: remote-desktop, vmware-horizon

My company recently migrated to `VMWare Horizon Client` for remote desktop solution. It's somehow really slow for me. My company IT department says they don't see any problems on their end, but I also don't see any problems on my internet speed test.

What can I do to make this faster? Is there any video quality related configs I can tune either on the remote side (unlikely I can tweak much of company network configs, but perhaps my work-PC config is tunable) or the client side (I use a windows 10 desktop)?

I don't need fancy high-resolution or high video quality for remote desktop. I am not sure if VMWare Horizon Client is also based on Microsoft Remote Desktop protocol?

Comment: @john a lot of this is about `PCoIP` protocol but my client is set to use "VMWare Blast" and it doesn't allow me to change that. What's the difference between these two protocols?

Comment: What are the differences in configuration and PC model amongst *your* PC and those who are not experiencing speed issues? Do you have any additional software installed, such as antimalware suite? Are the network parameters the same? As a last resort, if your no attached to the current PC setup, have IT reinstall the basic image.

Comment: @MattFrank - Your IT Administrator determines if PCoIP or VMWare Blast will be used. Actually the individual who configured the VMWare Horizons determines that, who of course is an Administrator, but a different type of Administrator